# Команда DROP не работает

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Всем привет, только начал изучать MySQL и почти сразу столкнулся с проблемой. Не работает команда DROP не смотря на то что в настройках разрешено удалять базу данных.Это первый вопрос.

Второй вопрос, можно ли создавать и удалять базы данных с помощью php файлов.

Пример:

CREATE DATABASE test;(что нужно сделать чтоб эта команда сработала в php, если это конечно вообще возможно). Ну или как создать базу данных вручную, не заходя в phpMyAdmim?

Comment: насчет возможности - рекомендую помедитировать над вот этой картинкой

> **php**MyAdmin

ну и как он делает можно посмотреть в его исходниках :) я думаю он просто посылает команду от рута "CREATE DATABASE AAAA";

Comment: `$db->query('create database test')` - только это не очень хорошая идея

можно отправить любой запрос через php и он выполнится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если не работает команда `DROP`, и права все верны, и подключились вы хорошо, то она не соответствует шаблону

```
DROP DATABASE `имя_БД`
```

безусловно можно создавать и удалять БД из скрипта.
после подключения ручками пишем:

```
mysql_query('запрос');
```

про виды запросов о БД можно почитать [здесь](http://www.spravkaweb.ru/mysql/sql/createdb).

Comment: [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)